# What's the most fair mining algorithm

Tags: mining-pools, hash

lots of people claim that Bitcoin's mining algorithm is unfair because ASIC has definite advantages over other chips. So, what can be the most fair algorithms that maximizes decentralization of mining?

Comment: I assume fair is here meant as "achieves the most decentralization", or do you want to include other criteria?

Comment: Yes so it is not easy to get an advantage

Comment: What is the definition of fair?

Comment: I'm also not sure. However there are lots of altcoins claiming they use more fair mining algorithms

Comment: Specialized hardware always have an advantage over generic hardware